# issue with login to magento 1.8 using jmeter

Tags: magento, testing, jmeter

one of my friend is using jmeter(Testing tool) for testing the magento 1.8 application.

But she is unable to log in using jmeter. Getting some error "no_cache cookie".

How this can be fixed? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar)? It may be a reason of error

Comment: tried to add HTTP Cookie Manager, but no success.There is no problem with magento 1.7.0.2